# How to convert daily build to a stable release?

Tags: upgrade, updates, release-management

Say, for example, I installed 13.04 daily build today. In 10+ days from today, 13.04 will be officially released (as stable).

After the release, do I need to do some sort of distribution upgrade? Or is it just a regular (a few packages) update?

Is it worth installing the daily build now, or should I wait 10 days and install clean? Is there a difference?